# I need authentication advice for an ASP.NET MVC 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a web application that will be used by the public.  This application has a login credentials requirement.

I don't want to create yet another site that you have to create a custom username/password combination unless you really want too.   I would like to support 3rd party logins like Facebook, Twitter, etc...

In the end this website could run in the Azure cloud as well so I am open to anything special to that.

One thing to note is the Microsoft Membership Provider that is part of ASP.NET is a great way to have custom login/passwords with a nice integration into MVC code.  What I would love is that Provider opened up to allow 3rd party logins.

Does anyone have any recommended solutions that they have had good success with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using [OpenID](http://openid.net/) like StackOverflow does. I have had good success using [`DotNetOpenAuth`](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/).

Comment: I think once DotNetOpenAuth gets Oauth 2.0 it will be a good choice.